# Will getting refused for a US B2 Tourist Visa complicate one's travels to another country?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I haven't tried applying for a US B2 Tourist Visa yet as my case is slightly complicated, as I'm not flying back to my home country but instead, I'm flying to a third country to further my studies as a Master's student. I have been in the US before, as an F-2 Visa holder, and even have a bank account there but I left after my divorce.

I'm actually very apprehensive about trying for it, as I've heard horror stories that if you don't get your B2 Tourist Visa, that's it, say goodbye to visiting the US in this lifetime. I've also read online that it might complicate your travels to other countries. Is any of this true?

Comment: It can complicate your travels to other countries in that some ask in their visa application about visa refusals from elsewhere (e.g. the UK). Being refused a US tourist visa doesn’t automatically mean you’d be refused elsewhere. What makes you so ‘apprehensive about trying for it’? You’ve asked 3 questions around the topic, is there a background to your US immigration history that causes you particular concern?

Comment: @Traveller Well, I've lived there previously, as an F-2 Visa Holder (a dependent). My ex-wife and I were in the "Green Card queue" until she decided she wanted to shack up with someone else, so she filed for divorce. I withdrew my Green Card application and left the US within the Grace period. So that part of my history worries me. The second is, as you probably know, the fact that I don't have strong ties with my country (except for family and property), and although I have more than enough money to enrol in a Master's and travel the world, I'm currently not working which I'm afraid might be

Comment: .... which might be viewed negatively by consular officers. 

That and the fact that I live by the book and like to follow rules and laws and know clear outcomes and like things that black and white, that can be viewed objectively  - and the B-2 tourist visa has a very subjective subsection 214(b) which is a boilerplate denial and can include a whole host of reasons that they a consular officer doesn't have to disclose.

Comment: That, and I was the kid who was deathly afraid of getting detention or any negative mark in my report card.

Comment: Don’t worry too much. Plenty of people obtain B2 visas on second and third attempts, sometimes within days of a refusal. Even more people travel to other countries after a B2 refusal. Only a handful of countries ask about previous visa refusals to other countries and while it may be a factor in the overall assessment, it doesn’t really matter that much.

Comment: The vast majority of people who apply for a US B visa receive it. Family and property _are_ considered strong ties to a country. And having enough income to travel all the time without working is fine.